# MFP 8 previewing app throws error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I am trying to preview the app in MFP 8 CLI.  But it throws the below error :

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 { Error: ERRGETSERVER
    at generateError (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev
-cli\node_modules\mdo-errors\lib\index.js:31:23)
    at Object.module.exports.getError (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\mdo-errors\lib\index.js:25:10)
    at readServerProfiles (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\m
fpdev-cli\node_modules\mdo-server-support\lib\profileIO.js:157:28)
    at C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modul
es\mdo-server-support\lib\profileIO.js:81:7
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cl
i\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modul
es\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli
\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\nod
e_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
  errno: 131,
  code: 'ERRGETSERVER',
  description: 'An error occurred during an attempt to read the server profiles.
' }
```

Comment: Could it be that you do not have admin rights?

Comment: I do have admin rights.

Comment: Can you please your mfpdev cli version

Comment: CLI version : mfpdev-cli@8.0.2017012016

Comment: Provide the full set of commands you are running